# Which cookie is used for SSO global session in KeyCloak?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

The KeyCloak solution is commonly utilized for Single Sign-On (SSO) purposes. SSO encompasses the concepts of both SSO Global Session and SSO Local Session. I have a few inquiries.

1. Which cookie is utilized for SSO global session in KeyCloak?
2. Which cookie is utilized for SSO local session in KeyCloak?
3. Where should the SSO local session be persisted? Is KeyCloak the appropriate solution for this?

I have follow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak to build a sample.